# Создание простой страничке силами индуса для радио

Tags: html5, sitemap

Здравствуйте, необходимо сделать простою страничку для местного радио по интернету. 
Фон при нажатии F5 или обновить страничку браузера будет всегда меняться, возможно заместо картинки будет красивая gif-анимация - понимаю, что в этом случае страничка потяжелеет, интересует может всё таки оставить просто картинку?
На страничке будет плеер который будет проигрывать радио
Также на страничке будет счётчик сколько людей сейчас сидит на этой страничке.

Вопрос: Какие минимальные знания нужны для создания сей страницы. Хочется, чтобы страничка была легко весом и без применения всевозможных cms т.е написана на языках программирования. Подозреваю необходимо будет воспользоваться технологией html4, думаю с сегодняшним развитием технологий есть смысл написать на html5. Какие еще необходимы технологии для данного проекта?
Заранее спасибо

З.Ы: Хотелось бы еще чтобы были иконки сообщества в викей, фейсбук, связь с админом через твиттер. А также расписание эфира. Ссылки на разное качество битрейда. И подскажите хостинг. Таймвеб будет нормас?? Также интересует как купить навсегда название сайта с доменной зоной, слышал это возможно только на 15 лет?
Всё это должно цивильно смотреться, я думаю, что немногое прошу :)

Answer (score 1):

> без применения всевозможных cms т.е написана на языках программирования

CMS тоже написаны на разных языках программирования. Ну в общем смысл понятен.

> Какие минимальные знания нужны для создания сей страницы. Хочется, чтобы страничка была легко весом

Знание javascript, знание как встраивается Flash в HTML-странички, ну и собственно сам HTML нужно знать. Счетчик можно взять мэйловский. Ну если сам хочешь сделать - то проще всего PHP :)

Answer (score 0):

Судя по твоим вопросам у тебя вряд ли получится это сделать.

Могу только порекомендовать не использовать .gif анимацию в качестве фона, а сделать подложку из видео, например в формате .WebM